# Convex constraint for the minimum of a vector

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

I am solving a second-order cone programming (SOCP) problem. I had to add a constraint that checks if at least one element of the decision variable vector is lower or equal to 0, i.e., I have to add the constraint
$$\min(y)\le0$$
Of course, this kind of constraint is concave and it is not compatible with SOCP.
Is there any way to write this constraint in a SOCP-like form?

Comment: Only as a mixed-integer socp.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to solve $n$ SOCP problems.  First solve one copy with the constraint $y_1\le 0$, then solve another copy with the constraint $y_2 \le 0$, and so on, then taking the best solution found amongst all of these.

However, this blows up if you have many of these constraints.